# OSGi Equinox: howto add protocol handler for LDAP?

Tags: java, ldap, osgi, equinox, malformedurlexception

I am having problems with adding a protocol handler for LDAP on OSGi environment. I tried:

- `System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "iaik.x509.net");`
- `-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=iaik.x509.net` in the Run Settings

but still get the `java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: ldap`

The protocol Handler for LDAP is in `iaik.x509.net` and is exported by its bundle. 
I am importing that bundle (that has `iaik.x509.net`) too. To me it seems that the System cannot find the package though. How do I "register" that protocol handler correctly?
I am running equinox 3.6.0 using java 1.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install `iaik.x509.net` bundle as a Framework extension bundle. It should contain MANIFEST header:

> Fragment-Host: system.bundle; extension:=bootclasspath

In this case LDAP protocol handler will be available for all bundles as a part of bootclasspath. Don't forget to set system property.

More details for extension bundles: OSGi Core Spec 4.2 - Chapter 3.14

Comment: I tried that but I get: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Boot classpath extensions are not supported.

Comment: try to set a system property to activate this functionality: 'org.osgi.supports.bootclasspath.extension=true'. Hope it is supported by framework. More details OSGi Core Spec 4.2, Chapter 3.14.3

Comment: take a look also at 'osgi.framework.extensions' equinox property (http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html)

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't the property be:  `-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=iaik.x509.net.ldap`  (it needs to be the package of the class extending URLConnection, from looking at [this](http://javadoc.iaik.tugraz.at/iaik_jce/current/iaik/x509/net/ldap/LdapURLConnection.html)).  To use it like this you'll have to add it to the Jar to boot classpath and export that package as part of the system bundle with `org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra=iaik.x509.net.ldap`

Alternatively turn it into a first class OSGi component.  Create a bundle that provides a wrapper for the handler with an implementation of `org.osgi.service.url.URLStreamHandlerService` that exports a service property `url.handler.protocol=ldap`

It's not much work to add a small bundle exporting the URLStreamHandlerService, this is definitely the way I'd go.

Comment: the protocol handler property won't work in OSGi (as long as the handler is in a bundle). It have to be a first class OSGi component

Comment: @J-16SDiZ +1 agreed, updating answer to indicate how to use as non-OSGi